# Include files from parent to other directories

Tags: php

I am building a website and has index.php in the root folder. The other pages are up to 2 folders deep and separated out by their different categories.

So the index.php file would be correct;

```
 <?php include ('/inc/head.php'); ?>
```

But the other pages would have to be;

```
<?php include ('../inc/head.php'); ?>  or  <?php include ('../../inc/head.php'); ?>
```

But this breaks the relative paths for the css and script files in the includes files themselves as they then don't map correctly! Any solutions?

Comment: Include relative to `__DIR__`, not your current working dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about paths set in `head.php`? Why not just use absolute paths? So rather than using `css/style.css` you'd do `/css/style.css`, etc.

Comment: Not sure how this solves the issue with the pages that are 2 folders deep as the paths in include/head.php won't map correctly?

Comment: Then I'm not clear on what you're asking, can you include a sample of head.php?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I got there in the end and posted answer above to explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I was getting confused and setting the relative paths in the footer and head sections as well as the 'includes'.

So the solution for the `head` and `footer` sections are,

```
<script src="../../js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Should be set as an absolute path as @ultranaut said:

```
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and the `include`, if the page is two folders deep from the root should then be:

```
<?php include ('../../inc/head.php'); ?>
```

Hope this helps some other PHP newbie too!